# Why do my speakers play audio when my headset is plugged in?

Tags: sound

I just got a new PC and I am a bit confused. I have a gaming headset and when I plug it into my PC, I can hear just fine. However, I realized that my sound was also coming through the speakers as well. My speakers are set for default, and when I set my headset to the communications default.. I am left with sound only coming through my speakers. When I change my settings to make the headset the default, it'll play through the speakers as it's told, but once the headset is unplugged there is no longer sound coming from the speakers.

When I don't have the headset plugged in, I want sound from my speakers.
When I have my headset plugged in, I want my sound to go ONLY there.

What can I do? 
I just purchased a new PC and this wasn't a problem. The speakers aren't new, nor is the headset.. so they are def working correctly. The sound card is Realtek.. (thats all I can tell from that.. its nothing fancy) I also have Windows 7 64 bit. The mobo is Asrock Pro 3. My speakers and my headset are both analog. I do not have a USB headset. Oh, and the drivers are ALL up to date. The headset is Corsair HS1.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I had the same problem when I was using Ubuntu 10.04 and it was due to a incomplete driver support. Everything is working just fine in 11.10 version (I have an `Conexant CX20582 (Pebble)` audio card). Could you update your question with the output of `cat /proc/asound/card?/codec#0 | grep Codec`? It would be easier to help.

Comment: Please see my answer in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69607/sound-plays-from-laptop-speakers-only-even-when-headphones-are-connected/69614#69614

possible duplicate

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that this depends on the soundcard that you are using, but you could at least check in `alsamixer` for something like "Auto-Mute Mode". Changing this on my laptop will bring up the problem (and solves it) you are describing.
[image]